# Installing external package, Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, rstudio

Trying to install a package through github and coming up with a connection error. I have a feeling it's because I'm using the most recent version of R for a mac, but can't see the package compatibility and so I can't tell, or it may be something else. I tried choosing 1–4 as update options and they all had the same issue.

```
> install.packages("remotes")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/remotes_2.4.2.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 396641 bytes (387 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 387 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/jv/9cqzkbhd28v_2_hrbxcb1nkh0000gn/T//Rtmp2RlS2k/downloaded_packages
> remotes::install_github("sivanMargalit/toolsForAtlas")
Downloading GitHub repo sivanMargalit/toolsForAtlas@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                            
2: CRAN packages only             
3: None                           
4: terra (1.7-39 -> 1.7-46) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: 1
terra (1.7-39 -> 1.7-46) [CRAN]
Installing 1 packages: terra
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/terra_1.7-39.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 97164930 bytes (92.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 92.7 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/jv/9cqzkbhd28v_2_hrbxcb1nkh0000gn/T//Rtmp2RlS2k/downloaded_packages
Running `R CMD build`...
* checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/jv/9cqzkbhd28v_2_hrbxcb1nkh0000gn/T/Rtmp2RlS2k/remotes4b024941dcfb/sivanMargalit-toolsForAtlas-01fd287/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘toolsForAtlas’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building ‘toolsForAtlas_0.0.0.9004.tar.gz’
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'renv/activate.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/jv/9cqzkbhd28v_2_hrbxcb1nkh0000gn/T//Rtmp2RlS2k/file4b025686bdc3/toolsForAtlas_0.0.0.9004.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: The error seems to be coming from the `renv` package. That doesn't seem to be referenced by `toolsForAtlas` at all. Is that something you installed for your own R version? Do you have a `.Rprofile` file that tries to initialize `renv`?

Comment: I didn't even notice that. I tried installing renv first (whatever it is) to see if it made a difference and got the same error. I tried to google that error, but am not sure how to change my r profile to remove the renv situation.